# Glassfish4 and JERSEY providers scanning

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey

When I'm deploying my app with Glassfish 3, there is:

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
```

And in this case i use:

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

in my web.xml, then everything is fine. Providers and root resources classes are found.

But when the same app is deploying with Glassfish 4, there is no any "scanning" for providers and root resource classes, and this causes the classes are not registered. Only one change is a servlet class to

```
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

wich glassfish4 is familiar.
   Why this happen? What should i do to force scanning?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your web.xml.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        ...
    </servlet>
    ...
</web-app>
```